# How can i animate display: none / block property on flex items?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, flexbox

Is there any way to animate `display: block/none` ?

When clicking on `div1` and `div 4` - I want to animate div's 2 and 3 respectively, (perfect would be to achieve also some nice transitions), while keeping them within a flex `.container`

So far, i can animate `visibility` and `opacity` (but in this case divs '2 and '3 while not-visible, still take space within `.container`) OR switch `display: none` to `block` (but then i lose `transition` of items).

I tried positioning inner div's `absolute`'ly, but then all responsiveness goes to hell...

Here's CodePen:
http://codepen.io/adamTrz/pen/jWOJMj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is best to do that with javascript or jQuery, and instead of switching to `display:none`, animate the `height` (or/and `width`) of the elements to 0 and then set them to `display:none`.

You might be interested in this page: http://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/ A lot of similar solutions have been proposed in the comments.

One of the comments is a pure css solution that I think is close to what you want:

**css**

```
div {
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    height:0;
    padding: 0 18px;
    width:100px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.animated {
    height:auto;
    padding: 24px 18px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/catharsis/n5XfG/17/

Comment: thanks, totally forgot that one can animate width and height :)

Comment: excellent answer